# Floor arrangement in persons and pet

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image]

I have tried this puzzle, but getting possibilities are more

First I have placed the positive scenarios in the floor arrangement

Q Lives on the floor 5  and top most floor is parrot

Then i arranged with 5 and 1 floor does not have cat

Possibility 1:

V placed in 4 floor and p dog placed in 3 floor

**for this i am getting so many chances , please anyone guide me for the answer with steps**

Comment: There is no reason for the question to be posted as an image. You really should post it as text, so that people who use screen readers will be able to understand the question.

Comment: Actually this is clearly not your puzzle; posting it here without attribution is plagiarism (and posting it at all, if you have no permission to do so, is probably copyright infringement).  Please attribute puzzles which are not your own creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First I'll work out the order of the animals. 
>  Listing them from floor 1 to 7, we know that we start with something that is not a cat, there are two cat-dog blocks, and we end with a parrot on floor 7. This means we have one of three possibilities:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  .CDCD.P
>  .CD.CDP
>  ..CDCDP
> ```
>
> But floor 5 is not a cat so only the first option works. There must be a dog that is not adjacent to a cat, so that gives:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  PCDCDDP
> ```
>
> Now lets turn to the people. Some are deduced directly:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  PCDCDDP
>  T...QR.
> ```
>
> Now P also only has one possibility as there is only one dog left:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  PCDCDDP
>  T.P.QR.
> ```
>
> Now so does V, as there is only one cat not below P:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  PCDCDDP
>  T.PVQR.
> ```
>
> S does not have a cat, which completes the puzzle:
>
> ```
>  1234567
>  PCDCDDP
>  TUPVQRS
> ```

Comment: Nice Explanation super well done @Jaap Scherphuis

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50622/blood-relations-in-deducing-family-tree guide me for this also @Jaap Scherphuis

Answer (score 0):

> According to 4 and 6, T can't have a cat. He/she doesn't own a dog either, so a parrot is the only possibility.
> Based on 6 and 8, R is the only dog owner who doesn't live immediately above a cat owner.
> Given 3, 6 and 7, V lives above P, there's a dog owner living immediately above V, and being one of the dog owners other than R, P has a cat owner living immediately below him/her. Combining that with 2 and 5, this means none of the four lives on the lowermost or top floors. Since Q is on the 5th floor, V lives on the 4th floor and P on the 3rd, making Q a dog owner, R the 6th-floor dweller, and the one living on the lowest floor a parrot owner. T can only be the latter and S must be living on the top floor.

In short:

> T - parrot, U - cat, P - dog, V - cat, Q - dog, R - dog, S - parrot (bottom to top)

Comment: How does your answer add to the identical, accepted one already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: If it's such a heinous crime, why are others let off the hook all the time?